# What is the best dictionary/translator?

Tags: software-recommendation, language-support, dictionary, translation

I want a dictionary or translator that uses or is similar to to Google translation for translating from English to Arabic, vice-versa or between any languages, so, what is the best one? It would be better if this program has an indicator or launcher quick-list.

Comment: Do you want a _widget_ to tap into **Google** translation, or do want a (free) app. ?

Comment: i want any thing (mmm, i think there is one widget for Cairo-dock) but it would be better to be an application.

Comment: Voting to reopen. AskUbuntu has several huge software recommendation questions, and they are extremely useful to the community. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/186626/translator-offline-for-ubuntu-and-free-dictionaries-which-of-them

Comment: Voting to reopen. AskUbuntu has several huge software recommendation questions, and they are extremely useful to the community. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/186626/translator-offline-for-ubuntu-and-free-dictionaries-which-of-them I also added an answer at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/380847/is-it-possible-to-translate-words-via-terminal/1309774#1309774

Answer (score 9):

This one may do the job:

```
sudo apt-get install artha
```

The HotKey is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. You can just select a word in any software and press the Hotkey combination to invoke Artha, its notification/window will then come up with the meaning

Comment: this Ctrl+Alt+w doesn't work sometime.. what shall i do?

Comment: no, there isn't any

Comment: actually i had to manually run artha after the system startup before this shortcut can actually work. Once i have used it without the shortcut it can later be used wit shortcut. how to enable it in startup programs, so that the dictionary runs at startup itself?

Answer (score 4):

I usually use "Gnome Translate" [image: Install gnome-translate] for this.  It's based on libtranslate, which can use several on-line services (including Google Translate, SYSTRAN, etc.) to translate text.

There is also a commandline version: `translate-bin`[image: Install translate-bin].

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
sudo apt-get install dictd dict-gcide dict-moby-thesaurus
```

Comment: these are 3 different dictionaries??               
which one shall i try??

Comment: i used these three commands and then searched in dash with keyword 'dict'. None of the results that turned up were working??? help plz

Comment: OMG ..got it. it's a command line dictionary. but i was asking for some GUI dictioary which supports word capture by means of  some keyboard shortcuts

Comment: '$ gnome-dictionary

The program 'gnome-dictionary' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gnome-dictionary'

Answer (score 1):

[Artha ~ The Open Thesaurus](http://artha.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Home)

This would be my recommendation.

[image]

Comment: Why not merging it with [answer]?(http://askubuntu.com/posts/193523/revisions)

Answer (score 1):

## Google Translate Desktop

You can install Google Translate Desktop, it's written in Java and because of that runs everywhere, it also uses the Google Translator API.

## Official Screenshots

[image]
[image]

## Download

Can be dowloaded here: [Google Code - Google Translate Desktop](http://code.google.com/p/google-translate-desktop/) (Last Release: July 28 2012).