# Translator offline for Ubuntu and free dictionaries, which of them?

Tags: software-recommendation, dictionary

I'm looking for a offline translator for Ubuntu 12.04.

I like **GoldenDict**, but I can't find dictionaries. I have looked for them on Google a lot but I can't find anything. I know about babylon dictionaries (.bgl); I've downloaded some of them from [babylon website](http://babylon.com) but it's a `.exe` file. I've tried every app to extract it (7zip, rar, ark, etc.) and finally I succeeded but there were no `.bgl` files in the archive.

I've also downloaded **free dict** from repository but they are not good for what I'm looking for (italian-english, english-italian).

Do you advice another app?

Or, if you think that GoldenDict is the best, do you know any sites to download dictionaries for GoldenDict (also ita-eng, eng-ita)?

Comment: Voting to reopen. AskUbuntu has several huge software recommendation questions, and they are extremely useful to the community. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/86795/what-is-the-best-dictionary-translator

Comment: I also added an answer at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/86795/what-is-the-best-dictionary-translator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org)

Designed as a **StarDict** successor, it supports its format, lots of other formats (Lingvo, Babylon etc), features tabbed browsing, morphology, **live pronunciations**, **Wikipedia** and so on. As a free software, it is constantly being improved and worked on.

[image: SS0]
[image: SS1]

**[Dictionaries](http://goldendict.org/dictionaries.php)**

The most common dictionaries are Babylon (.bgl) but their problems is that are **no longer officially supported**.
So my recommendation is use the StarDict dictionaries. In [this website](http://www.stardict.org/download.php) you will find a library with hundreds of dictionaries.
**How to install them:** Open GoldenDict and select `Edit -> Dictionaries -> Add` then select the extracted folder and click `Apply`.

**[Donwload and Install](http://goldendict.org/download.php)**

1. Download the [source code](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/goldendict/goldendict-1.0.1-src.tar.bz2)
2. Uncompress it (with second click you'll see the option)
3. Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
4. Enter `cd uncompressed_folder`
5. Enter the following commands in order:
   `qmake`
   `make`
   `sudo make install`

Comment: ok thanks a lot, so I made a good choice with goldendict. But about the dictionaries I can't download them, it says that the dictionary doesn't exit and it sends me to http://sourceforge.net/projects/stardict/files/

Comment: On Lubuntu when try `qmake` i get `qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''`

Comment: Golden dict is now in ubuntu repository and looks that version 1.5 is managing BLG file without issues