# Dictionary for 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best dictionary/translator for ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86795/what-is-the-best-dictionary-translator-for-ubuntu)

Is there any dictionary supported by 12.04 which has the feature of word capture by use of few key strokes from my keyboard?[image]